# NiFi https setup giving certificate error

Tags: unix, openssl, apache-nifi, truststore, jks

I am facing weird issue. this may very well not just be nifi(1.9.2) issue, but some other factor.

the steps i am trying to do is not new, i have done this on multiple boxes (i have 10 boxes, running with similar setup)

1) OS - unix
2) DNS is internal
3) https certificate is not self-signed, they are CA signed.

certificate generation process.

1) i generate csr on unix command line

```
openssl genrsa -out key.file 2048

openssl req -sha256 -new -key key.file -out out.csr
```

2) then i shared CSR file with 3rd party, and they got me certificate chain.

this above mentioned process was followed with all my previous setups (10 boxes). never faced this issue.

now i am facing this weird issue. (attached screenshot).

this message is very deceptive, as per internet search, nifi is rejecting my certificate/identity. but why is my identity? what certificate my connection must be presenting to nifi? and are we suppose to add everyone who is trying to come to nifi to be in nifi's trust store?

I have not face this issue with any of my previous setups :( , so cant put my finger on what must be going on.

this is not just chrome issue, i am getting similar error on all 4 big browsers.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

NiFi is telling your browser that you must present a *client certificate* in order to authenticate to the system. This is likely because you have not configured any other authentication mechanism (LDAP, Kerberos, OpenID Connect, etc.). You can read more about these authentication mechanisms in the [Apache NiFi Admin Guide](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#user_authentication).

> NiFi can only be configured for username/password, OpenId Connect, or
>   Apache Knox at a given time. It does not support running each of these
>   concurrently. NiFi will require client certificates for authenticating
>   users over HTTPS if none of these are configured.

If you do not want to configure any of these other mechanisms, you can still authenticate using a client certificate. In order for your certificate to be accepted, it must be signed by (or *be*) a certificate whose public key is loaded as a `trustedCertEntry` in the NiFi truststore. The [NiFi Toolkit Guide](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/toolkit-guide.html#additional_certificate_commands) may help with the explicit commands you need in order to configure this.

If this isn't sufficient to solve your problem, you'll need to share more information, including your `nifi.properties` file (redact the sensitive values like keystore/truststore password), the output of `keytool -list -v -keystore /path/to/truststore.jks`, and the output of `keytool -list -v -keystore /path/to/client.p12 -storetype PKCS12`.

Comment: i think this was much more near to the problem i was facing (first part of your answer).

Answer (score 1):

Rakesh,

I would check these things as well:

- Your browser should contain a client certificate signed by the same
  CA the NiFi server certificate was signed by. The browser will prompt
  which certificate to use when you visit the NiFi UI.
- The CA public certificate should be added to NiFi's trust store. This will allow
  NiFi server to trust the client certificate in your browser.
- Your client certificate DN needs to be added to the authorizers.xml file
  as an Initial Admin, and you need to remove users.xml and
  authorizations.xml and restart NiFi.

Comment: although this was my gut feel too, but certificate was provided by CA, and my browser do have that too.